# Javascript atualiza diversos inputs

Tags: javascript

Com a ajuda do @luccascosta consegui fazer funcionar um código em que, ao clicar em um checkbox, ele captura o valor desse checkbox e atualiza o valor em outro input.
O problema agora é que ao clicar nesse checkbox, preciso atualizar diversos inputs ao mesmo tempo.
Até consegui fazer os cálculos, mas agora não consigo jogar o resultado nos seus respectivos inputs.

Observem o código:

```
var evento = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]');
for (let i = 0; i < evento.length; i++) {
    evento[i].addEventListener('click', AddValor);
}

function AddValor() {
  var val_evento = parseFloat(this.value, 10);

  var pacote = new Array();
  $('.valor_principal').each(function() {
    pacote.push($(this).val());
  });

  for (let i = 0; i < pacote.length; i++) {
    var total = jQuery.parseJSON(pacote[i]);

    this.checked == true ? total += val_evento : total -= val_evento;

    alert(total);

    pacote[i].value = total;
  }
}

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="evento_value1" value="99.00">
<input type="checkbox" id="evento_value2" value="120.00">
<input type="checkbox" id="evento_value3" value="99.00">
<input type="checkbox" id="evento_value4" value="300.00">
<input type="checkbox" id="evento_value5" value="5.00">

<input class="valor_principal" value="100">
<input class="valor_principal" value="200">
<input class="valor_principal" value="300">
```

No alert(total) vocês podem observar o resultado acontecendo...
Aogra, preciso que ele atualize os valores em cada 
Obrigado pela ajuda...

Comment: Mas tens 5 cehckbox só para 3 inputs, como funciona?

Comment: Pois é... mas é isso mesmo...

Comment: Os checkboxs são eventos opcionais e os inputs class="valor_principal" é o valor de cada pacote. Ao clicar em um checkbox, é preciso atualizar os valores de todos os inputs class="valor_principal".

Comment: Preciso que o "valor_principal" sejam input, pois o vendedor poderá ainda alterar o valor final, tirando de sua comissão...

Comment: Mas não deveria cinco checkboxes para 5 inputs? O que deve acontecer com 2 checkboxes que não estão cobertos por inputs?  O que significa cada checkbox em relação a cada input?

Comment: Os checkboxes e os inputs class="valor_principal' não tem relação direta...
Imagina o seguinte. Você foi em uma agência de viagem e eles detam 3 opções de viagens (valor_principal", mas você tem 5 eventos opcionais para incluir se quiser.

Comment: O que quero fazer é, quando eu escolher um evento opcional, acrescenta o valor desse evento em todas as viagens oferecidas...

Comment: Ha ok, percebi Rafael, vou ajudar

Comment: Obrigado @Miguel

Comment: Pode ser com jQuery certo? Já que o estás a importar..

Comment: Sem problemas, pode ser sim...

Answer (score 0):

Veja se isso te ajuda (dá para melhorar)

```js
var evento = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]');
for (let i = 0; i < evento.length; i++) {
    evento[i].addEventListener('click', AddValor);
}

function AddValor() {
  var val_evento = parseFloat(this.value, 10);

  var pacote = new Array();
  $('.valor_principal').each(function() {
    pacote.push($(this).val());
  });

  for (let i = 0; i < pacote.length; i++) {
    var total = jQuery.parseJSON(pacote[i]);

    this.checked == true ? total += val_evento : total -= val_evento;

    
    if(i==0)
    var x = document.getElementById('a').value = total;
    if(i==1)
    var y = document.getElementById("b").value = total;
    if(i==2)
    var z = document.getElementById("c").value = total;
    
    //alert(pacote.length);

    pacote[i].value = total;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="evento_value1" value="99.00">
<input type="checkbox" id="evento_value2" value="120.00">
<input type="checkbox" id="evento_value3" value="99.00">
<input type="checkbox" id="evento_value4" value="300.00">
<input type="checkbox" id="evento_value5" value="5.00">

<input class="valor_principal" id="a" value="100">
<input class="valor_principal" id="b" value="200">
<input class="valor_principal" id="c" value="300">
```

Answer (score 0):

Acrescentei a class `evento` aos checkboxes para ficar de facil seleção (mas também dá `$('input[type="checkbox"]')`, se tiveres a certeza que são só esses), e `data-val` aos inputs para guardar os valores originais

```js
var val_p, sum_ev;
$('.evento').on('change', function() {
  sum_ev = 0;
  $('.evento:checked').each(function() {
    sum_ev += Number($(this).val());
  });
  $('.valor_principal').each(function() {
    val_p = Number($(this).data('val'))+sum_ev;
    $(this).val(val_p);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" class="evento" id="evento_value1" value="99.00">
<input type="checkbox" class="evento" id="evento_value2" value="120.00">
<input type="checkbox" class="evento" id="evento_value3" value="99.00">
<input type="checkbox" class="evento" id="evento_value4" value="300.00">
<input type="checkbox" class="evento" id="evento_value5" value="5.00">

<input class="valor_principal" data-val="100" value="100">
<input class="valor_principal" data-val="200" value="200">
<input class="valor_principal" data-val="300" value="300">
```